# Is the ground track of any GNSS satellite constant? (or does it drift?)

Tags: gps

The from Wikipedia [Global Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) pageone can see that the GPS satellites have repeating ground track

> Orbiting at an altitude of approximately 20,200 km (12,600 mi);
> orbital radius of approximately 26,600 km (16,500 mi),[86] each SV
> makes two complete orbits each sidereal day, **repeating the same ground
> track each day**

- Is the ground track of the satellites belonging to the other GNSS systems (Galileo, Glonass, Beidou) always the same?
- Because of nonidealities, such as solar radiation pressure, the satellite orbits, and thus, the ground tracks have errors. Will the ground track be corrected back to the "average ground track" somehow, or *is it possible that the ground track drifts with time*? (during months or years)

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents on your questions:

- All Global Navigation Satellite Systems (GNSS) have ground track repeating with a time that varies according to the GNSS. Evidence of this for GPS, GLONASS and Galileo is given e.g., in a nice table reported in the text book [Hofmann-Wellenof, 2008, p. 398](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783211730126)
  [image: GPS, GLONASS and Galileo at a Glance, Hofmann-Wellenof, 2008, p. 398]
- The *nonidealities* you talk about (e.g., solar radiation pressure), are corrected by applying some model and the residual error that is left on the satellite orbit amount to few centimeter, at the most. Therefore, depending on the accuracy requirements you are after, you can think of the ground tracks of GNSS as constantly repeating ones (i.e., not drifting with time). Nowadays, the International GNSS Service (IGS) can achieve precisions of 1-2 centimeters in computing the GNSS orbits [On the Precision and Accuracy of IGS Orbits](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226287811_On_the_Precision_and_Accuracy_of_IGS_Orbits), [IGS products description](http://www.igs.org/products), [Access to the GNSS orbit products](https://cddis.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/GNSS/orbit_products.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think this answers to the question "Is the ground track of the satellites belonging to the other GNSS systems always the same?" for Galileo and GLONASS. The broadcast GPS ephemeris 3d accuracy is [about 2 meters](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5492036/pdf/sensors-17-01363.pdf), on which I base an assumption that the satellites move from the ideal paths up so ~2m. Even if the movement would be 2cm, what force would make the GNSS satellites ground track not drift in longer term?